# Java JTS Polygon contains Another Polgyon

Tags: java, jts, java-15

I am trying to use JTS to tell if one Polygon contains another Polygon.

I have resources here. How do I utilize the syntax? this is giving me errors. The next step is to apply contains. If anyone has experience with JTS, it would be helpful.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368520/jts-geometry-contains-not-detecting-point-of-an-inner-polygon-on-edge-of-outer

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262751/how-to-determine-if-one-polygon-is-contained-in-another

https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Polygon.html

```
Polygon item1 = ((0 0, 1000 0, 1000 1000, 0 1000, 0 0))
Polygon item2 = ((500 500, 1000 500, 600 600, 500 600, 500 500))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create a polygon just like that. JTS is a rather heavy framework, so you need to go the full route.

1. Everything starts with `GeometryFactory`[docs](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/GeometryFactory.html). It is responsible for creating all geometries, it is necessary because it takes into account a few things like `PrecisionModel` for example.
2. You need to understand the hierarchy of geometries, `Polygon` is described by a line - `LineRig` or `LineString` (the difference is out of the scope for this question).
3. You need to realize that every line consists of points, which can be described either by `Point` or `Coordinate`. So if you want to create a `Polygon`

The code would look like this:

```java
 GeometryFactory factory = new GeometryFactory(); //default
 Coordinate[] coordinates1 = {
        new CoordinateXY(0,0),
        new CoordinateXY(1000,0),
        new CoordinateXY(1000, 1000),
        new CoordinateXY(0, 1000),
        new CoordinateXY(0, 0)
 };
 Coordinate[] coordinates2 = {
        new CoordinateXY(500,500),
        new CoordinateXY(1000,500),
        new CoordinateXY(600, 600),
        new CoordinateXY(500, 600),
        new CoordinateXY(500, 500)
 };
 LinearRing linearRing1 = factory.createLinearRing(coordinates1);
 LinearRing linearRing2 = factory.createLinearRing(coordinates2);
 Polygon polygon1 = factory.createPolygon(linearRing1);
 Polygon polygon2 = factory.createPolygon(linearRing2);
 assertTrue(polygon1.contains(polygon2));
```